# How to store number of object element of array in another array?

Tags: javascript

im trying to store some object element from one array to another so lets say i have this array of objects

```
var Array = [{name:'Fadi'},{name:'Joseph'},{name:'Salim'},{name:'Tony'}];
```

and i want to store the first two object in this array to another array so it would like be

```
var SubArray =[{name:'Fadi'},{name:'Joseph'}];
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ok, so `SubArray = [Array[0],Array[1]]`, else you need to define you question a lot better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method for this:

```
var SubArray = Array.slice(0,2);
```

Please note that [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is reserved JS global object. You need to use different name for that variable. So your code should be for example:

```
var MyArray = [{name:'Fadi'},{name:'Joseph'},{name:'Salim'},{name:'Tony'}];
var SubArray = MyArray.slice(0,2);
```

Comment: +1 for using a standard built-in function. MDN has a good documentation on [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and JS in general.

Comment: @antyrat if i want to add some new property like number to the sliced object can i do it directly with the slice or just loop on each object in the SubArray  and add the new property.

Comment: Probably you need to loop

Answer (score 0):

If you need conditional logic you want [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). If you know you always want the items by index then use [slice as in antyrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26302844/361762).

```
var originalArray = [{name:'Fadi'},{name:'Joseph'},{name:'Salim'},{name:'Tony'}];
var subArray = originalArray.filter(function(obj,index) {
    return obj.name=="Fadi" || obj.name=="Joseph";
})
```